# How to switch between panels using Jbutton multiple classes

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jbutton, actionlistener

I am having problems with figuring how to use event handlers in order to remove and repaint between 2 panels.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelSwitcherView extends JFrame {
private JPanel panel1, panel2;

public PanelSwitcherView() {
    super("Panel Switching Test");

    Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 30);
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));

    font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 30);
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Here I decided to add a test ActionListener but am unsure if correctly used

```
    font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 30);
    JButton button = new JButton("Switch Panels");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          System.out.print("Test");
          PanelSwitcherModel.switchPanel(); // used to make value of whichpanel 1 or 2
       }
    });
    button.setFont(font);
    add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Not completely sure how to use this either

```
    public void displayPanel(int whichPanel) {
    remove(panel1);
    remove(panel2); 
    if (whichPanel == 1) {
        System.out.println("Should display panel1");
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Should display panel2");
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    validate();
    repaint();
}
```

My Controller (class below)

```
public void register(PanelSwitcherController controller) {

   }
```

Problem lies mainly here, I am a newbie here, do I move my ActionListener here somehow? How do I access other classes in order to change the number from 1 to 2 for my panel options?

```
import java.awt.event.*;


public class PanelSwitcherController implements ActionListener{

  public PanelSwitcherController(PanelSwitcherView view,
         PanelSwitcherModel model) {
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   }

   }
```

Comment: Your listener needs access to the panels or at least access to a method that switches the panels on an object that does have access to them. Then just remove one panel and add the other. You might also have to call revalidate after the switch.

Comment: Can you give a clear definition of what you mean by `switch between panels`.

Comment: You would do better to give an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @peeskillet I am trying to click a JButton and when the click is done, the JPAnel will switch between panel1 and panel2.

Comment: ok, let ME be more clear. What does `switch` entail? I can't see your GUI, so I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @peeskillet Changing from one panel to another, removing the previous and repainting with the new one, either panel1 or panel2. When the JButton is to be clicked, there should be an event where switchPanel changes the static value of panel from 1 to 2 or from 2 to 1. How do I implement this ActionListener and event correctly?

Comment: @Daniel Anthony. I posted an answer. I think this is what you're talking about. I'm too lazy to try and work on your code. There's too much going on in it. So I made an example implementation of such an action.

Comment: @peeskillet I have updated my question a bit, hopefully this helps out

Comment: @DAniel Anthony, you do realize that your method id `displayPanels()`, but yet in your `actionPerformed()` tries to invoke `switchPanel()`.  Also, does my answer not help you figure this problem out. All you had to do was switch a few things around. I thought it was pretty straight forward.